# Getting conflicting types error for function but parameters match

Tags: c

I know you get a conflicting types error when the parameters of the function prototype and actual function is different. But that does no seem to be the case with this function I wrote to remove all occurrences of a character from a linked list. Not sure if the code will work, but I can't find out because I keep getting conflicting types error. This is the node definition,

```
typedef struct node{
char c;
struct node*next;
}Node,*NodePtr;
```

This is the prototype

```
NodePtr remove(NodePtr,char);
```

This is the function

```
NodePtr remove(NodePtr top,char ch){
NodePtr prev,curr;
curr=top;
while(curr!=NULL&&curr->c==ch)
{top=curr->next;
free(curr);
curr=top;}//if head node contains ch or multiple occurrences
while(curr!=NULL)
{
    while(curr!=NULL&&curr->c!=ch)
    {
        prev=curr;
        curr=curr->next;
    }
    prev->next=curr->next;
    free(curr);
    curr=prev->next;// update curr
}
return top;
}// end of remove
```

I have no idea why I'm getting conflicting types error.

Comment: You probably have a call to the function before the prototype, but this code doesn't show that.  Please create a [mcve] that generates the same error.

Comment: In the future, when asking about an error you are getting, show the exact text of the error message. Since you have not, and this problem was trivial and is solved, you should delete the question.

Comment: Please also show the MCVE as requested by dbush for every future question. These tiny parts are not enough to diagnose what happened.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the problem. The function name remove is already the name of a function in the c library or something. I have to change the function name. I changed the name and the code compiled. So that fixed the "conflicting types error" problem. My function implementation is wrong anyway.

Comment: In that case you should get some message telling you which parameter types are expected and they should be really different from what you have defined. The standard function is `int remove(const char *path);`

Comment: @Gerhardh shouldn't also the compiler get angry when redefining functions?

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica This probably depends on what headers were included where and in which order. If `stdio.h` was not (yet) visible when the "wrong" `remove` function was declared, there might be no error message.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica: There is no redefinition of a function in this source code. The `<stdio.h>` header declares the function; it does not define it. So the compiler does not see any redefinition. When the program is linked, there will be two definitions, one in the user’s object module and one in the standard C library, but typical link policies are that it is fine for a library module to offer a symbol that is already defined; that module from the library will simply not be used.

Comment: @EricPostpischil just tried; my compiler says "Declaration is incompatible with "str fmt3(int __near)" (declared at line 17 of "../src/utility.h")" when trying to declare (not define) "str fmt3(str what);".

Comment: @Gerhardh but... if the compiler was giving error, then the compiler should have seen (already) the original remove(), otherwise it would have not a reason to complain, right?

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica: That is an error about incompatible declarations, not an error about redefining a function.

Comment: Yes. But we do not have enough code to tell where the message was given and whether the header was already included at this pointt

Comment: @EricPostpischil just tried to write the function without a prototype. Same error, this time pointing to the definition. Maybe my compiler is not the best, but perhaps better than the OP one.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica: And the message you got was still complaining about incompatible declarations, not a redefinition. A declaration of a function identifier tells the compiler about the type of the function. A definition of a function also includes the function body. The `<stdio.h>` header contains only a declaration of `remove`, not a definition, so a definition of `remove` in source code cannot be a duplicate definition of anything in `<stdio.h>` because there is no such definition in `<stdio.h>`.